# Having Issue on Getting json_encode() On Mysqli Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am having some problem on exporting the result of a Prepared Statement using MySQLi.

```
$age = "young";
$rows = array();
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT fname, lname FROM users WHERE age=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $age);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($thefName,$thelName);
                while($stmt->fetch()) 
                  {
                    array_push($rows, $thefName,$thelName);
                  }
            $stmt->close();

$mysqli->close();
echo json_encode($rows);
```

as you can see I am trying to echo out the `json_encode($rows);` each of rows as a JSON Array like this  :

```
[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]
```

but what I am getting is

```
["John", "Doe", "Anna", "Smith", "Peter", "Jones"]
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the proper array -

```
array_push($rows, array('firstName' => $thefName, 'lastName' => $thelName));
```

Comment: Thanks b0s3, just for my clarification! this is presenting data in JSON format, right? and the way that I was printing was a simple Array? am I correct?

Comment: After using `json_encode` it will be an json string.